# How to make my submit button theme with spring and dojo

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo

How do I make my form button like look the other fields on the form with Spring Webflow and digit

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration(
                                                {
                                                    elementId : 'submit',
                                                    widgetType : "dijit.form.Button",
                                                    widgetModule : "dijit.form.Button"
                                                }));
                            </script> 

        <p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my code to the following and it works:

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration(
                                                {
                                                    elementId : 'submit',
                                                    widgetType : "dijit.form.Button",
                                                    widgetModule : "dijit.form.Button",
                                                    widgetAttrs : {
                                                        label: "Submit Page",
                                                        promptMessage : "Click here to submit page"
                                                    }

                                                }));
                            </script>
```